# Bootstrap 4 Modal js trigger not working?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a modal and I want to ask the user to authenticate before showing the modal (that overrides server files with the modal content).

I want the user to click on my editmodal button, to show a connection form and if it's the same as my json base64 encoded data the modal get shown.

My problem: I can't get my modal to be shown with any of those

```
$('#Modal').modal();
$('#Modal').modal('toggle');
$('#Modal').modal('show');
```

my code is :

```
<button id="buttonmodal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-target="#exampleModal">
```

(i removed the data-trigger for i want to do it in js)

```
<!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content" style="    width: 600px;
          height: 600px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button id="closebtn" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form action="" name="modal-form" style="width: 100%; height:70%" method="post">
              <textarea id="textarea_modal" name="textarea_modal" style="min-width: 100%; min-height:100%"></textarea>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="buttonSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and my js is pretty simple for now :

```
$('#buttonmodal').click(function() {
debugger;
 var text = $('#data').text();
 $('#textarea_modal').val(text);
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
});
```

If ever you have tips or other way to do it, it would help a lot.

Comment: Remove the php tag, this is not a php related question

Comment: Do you see any errors in `console`?

Comment: Nop i got no errors in console, jquery finding the event and all i could debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i was dumb, the solution was : my css link where point on bootstrap 4.3 where my script was going on an older version so i had conflict version that wern't shown in the console.

Ty for those who helped

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for id "Modal", while your component is using a class "modal" with an id "exampleModal". `<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`

To fix this you might want to change your code to:

```
$('.modal').modal();
$('.modal').modal('toggle');
$('.modal').modal('show');
```

or

```
$('#exampleModal').modal();
$('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
$('#exampleModal').modal('show');
```

It all depends on how you would like to be finding your component.

> Note: **#** is used for **ids**, while **.** for **classes**

Comment: i wanted to tell i used them, if you look in the js script its     $('#exampleModal').modal('show');

Comment: Did you notice you are keeping the "debugger" within the click function, this might be stopping you testing it and all you need to do might be to proceed forward? Otherwise, any other console errors?

Comment: ahah yes but its not what is posing an issue here

Comment: does your "var text = $('#data').text();" return data? you might want to double check this too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 4 Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Button to Open the Modal 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="buttonmodal">
      Open modal
    </button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">

          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="" name="modal-form" style="width: 100%; height:70%" method="post">
            <textarea id="textarea_modal" name="textarea_modal" style="min-width: 100%; min-height:100%"></textarea>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="buttonSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


<script>
    $('#buttonmodal').click(function() {
    debugger;
     var text = $('#data').text();
     $('#textarea_modal').val("test 123");
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```